# Missing DataGridview scrollbar C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, text-files, freeze

I have WindowsForm solution with a datagridview to display the data that I read from text file. The number of rows from data is large, about 10.000 lines.

When I run the program from visual studio, it seems fine. But when I run it from the Debug folder (.exe file), then something goes wrong with my datagridview. The scroll-bar is missing.

Here is how I fill the datagridview:

```
private void LoadInputData()
    {
        try
        {
            InputDataGridView.DataSource = null;
            InputDataGridView.Refresh();
            InputDataGridView.DataSource = inputDataTable;
            DisableCells();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Load Input Data Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

I have a function that is designed to fill the `inputDataTable` from a text file. The `DisableCells()` function is to lock the datagridview (i.e. set the `readonly properties` be `true`) and customize the column length.

The data still can be scrolled by mouse. How does it happen? How do I solve this?

Here is preview of my program: [link](http://i58.tinypic.com/qn6xys.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problems. It caused by backgroundworker. I do not know how to explain the concept technicaly. But, here that I did.

I move the `LoadInputData();` line. Previously, I put it inside `private void OpenDataBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)` function. Then, I moved it to the another place outside the background worker. It can seen in this code below.

**Previously:** 
(see the "//")

```
private void OpenDataBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //LoadInputData();
            CalculateRowAndColumnInNumericUpDown();
            mainForm.MainToolStripProgressBar.Value = 0;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            OpenDataButton.Enabled = true;

            ProcessGroupBox.Enabled = true;
            ClearAllDataButton.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Open Data Background Worker RunWorkerCompleted Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

**To this place:**

```
private void OpenDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenDataButton.Enabled = false;

            if (!OpenDataBackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                OpenFileDialog openData = new OpenFileDialog();
                openData.Multiselect = true;
                openData.ShowDialog();
                openData.Filter = "allfiles|*";

                if (openData.FileName != "")
                {
                    ClearInputDataTable();
                    LoadInputData();
                    OpenDataBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                    OpenDataBackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                    OpenDataBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(openData.FileName);
                }
            }
            //here!!!
            LoadInputData();
            OpenDataButton.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error - Open Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have exactly the same.
Fix by setting "datagridview.Datasource = NULL" before background loading and set it back after: "datagridview.Datasource = bindingsource"

Answer (score 0):

add something like this to add scroll bars to the datagridview if the scroll bars are missing

```
InputDataGridView.ScrollBars == Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both
'or
InputDataGridView.ScrollBars == Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical
```

Comment: I did your suggestion. But it did not resolve my issue. There are traces scrolbarr in that place, but with white color. The process also work longer than when I run it from visual studio.

Comment: this is the preview of my program (click on the link): [link](http://i58.tinypic.com/qn6xys.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (productsDataGridView.InvokeRequired) { 
    productsDataGridView.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { LoadInputData() })); 
}
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, you should improve the quality of your answer by explaining what this code does and how it is meant to fix the original problem -- this helps other users reading your answer understand what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

simple add this line after you call disable cells method

```
myDataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
```